# Copying resources using SBT

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a Scala project, using SBT. I have a directory `html` inside my project which needs to be copied when the project is being run with `sbt run`, or when I package it into a Jar using `sbt-assembly`. Either way, I'll expect to have the `html` directory copied to `target/scala-2.11/classes/html`.

I have tried:

```
resourceDirectory in Compile := file("html")
```

...which moves each of the files inside `html` to `target/scala-2.11/classes` without the intermediate `html` directory.

and:

```
unmanagedResources in Compile := Seq(file("html"))
```

...which copies the directory, but none of the files inside it!

Comment: Why don't you just put `html` into some other directory and then add it to `unmanagedResourceDirectories`?

Comment: I could, but I'd rather not have a more complex directory structure just because of SBT's limitations

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not so nice, but working:

```scala
val html = "html"

lazy val compileCopyTask = taskKey[Unit](s"Copy $html.")

compileCopyTask := {

  println(s"Start copying $html")
  val mainVersion = scalaVersion.value.split("""\.""").take(2).mkString(".")
  val to = target.value / ("scala-" + mainVersion) / html / "classes"
  to.mkdirs()
  val from = baseDirectory.value / html
  IO.copyDirectory(from,to)
  println(s"$from  -> $to...done.")
}

compile in Compile := {
  compileCopyTask.value
  (compile in Compile).value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you run `sbt copy-resources`after you `sbt compile`
you might have some luck. Ran into this recently.

your html folder will have to be in scr/main/resources or wherever your resourceDirectory is set in your build....